# How to measure the level of tail dependence in copula?

Tags: correlation, copula, marginal-distribution, kurtosis, heavy-tailed

In the Clayton copula below, we see that there is stronger **lower tail dependence** (bottom left corner of Clayton) than **upper tail dependence** (upper right corner) because the pseudo-observation pairs in the bottom left corner of the Clayton graph are much darker than those in the upper right corner.

[image]

For this, and more importantly for cases where the visual distinction is not as obvious, are there any statistical measures or tests that can be used to numerically confirm whether lower/upper tail dependence is stronger than in the other tail and by how much?

And which of those measures are better capable of measuring asymmetric rather than (or as well as) symmetric differences in tail dependence?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tail_dependence